# I don't see the features of GridView set using jquery on the page javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a problem with the attributes of a `GridView`. In the `aspx` page I have a `<div>` .

```
<div id="DivRecords">
```

and inside this I put a `GridView` dynamically using `jQuery`. In the `js` file I create the `GridView`:

```
$("#DivRecords").append("<asp:GridView ID=gvCustomers runat=server AutoGenerateColumns=false OnRowDataBound=GridView1_RowDataBound RowStyle-BackColor=#A1DCF2 HeaderStyle-BackColor=#3AC0F2 HeaderStyle-ForeColor=White>");
    $("#DivRecords").append("<Columns>");
    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfValue.length; i++) {
        $("#DivRecords").append("<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width=250px DataField=" + arrayOfValue[i] + " HeaderText=" + arrayOfHeader[i] + "/>");              
    }

    $("#DivRecords").append("</Columns>");
    $("#DivRecords").append("</asp:GridView>");
```

In the webpage of browser there isn't the `RowStyle-BackColor`, the `HeaderStyle-BackColor` and I can't invoke the event `GridView1_RowDataBound`.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** create `server-side` controls (i.e., asp.net controls) using JavaScript. You can only create `client-side` controls (i.e., html controls).

You can use datatables (https://www.datatables.net/) or jgrid (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609442/Using-JqGrid-in-ASP-NET) for similar purposes.

Answer (score 0):

**No you can't add server-side control from client side**

Gridview control is asp.net server-side  control which is used to display tabular form data. You may have notice in .aspx page on page load every asp.net control gets convert into respected HTML tag.

For gridview its converted into `<Table>` (html tag).

For Label its converted into `<span>` (html tag) .....

So this mean you can add respected html tag from client side with javascript / jQuery. But not server side control will get added from client side.

For tabular data [jquery Datatable](https://www.datatables.net/) is good choice , also check [jTable](http://www.jtable.org/) , [dynatable](http://www.dynatable.com/)